# Automatic Login

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to automatically login a user. The JavaScript code below here actually does that but only when I remove the 'login/submit' div (), and then stops working when I include the 'div'. I can't remove this 'div' as that is my submit button. I don't know how to get around this problem, any help will be appreciated.

HTML;

```
<body>

<form name="EventConfirmRedirection" class="Form" method="post" action="index.php" id="myForm" data-ajax="false">
  <div class="user_login3"><input style="text-transform:lowercase" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username"></div> 
  <div class="user_login3"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password"></div>

    <div style="margin-left:5%; width:45%; font-size:5px;">
        <input data-theme="c" type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe"/>
        <label for="rememberMe"><span style="font-size:12px">remember me</span></label>
    </div>   

    <div style="margin-left:5%; color:#FF0000; font-weight:bold" id="error"></div>



    <div class="login"><input type="submit" value="LOGIN" name="submit" data-theme="e" id="submit"></div>
</form>

</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

"use strict";

    if (window.localStorage.checkBoxValidation && window.localStorage.checkBoxValidation !== '') {
        $('#rememberMe').attr('checked', 'checked');
        $('#username').val(window.localStorage.userName);
        $('#password').val(window.localStorage.passWord);
        document.EventConfirmRedirection.submit();
    } else {
        $('#rememberMe').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#username').val('');
        $('#password').val('');
    }

     $('#rememberMe').click(function() {

        if ($('#rememberMe').is(':checked')) {
            // save username and password
            window.localStorage.userName = $('#username').val();
            window.localStorage.passWord = $('#password').val();
            window.localStorage.checkBoxValidation = $('#rememberMe').val();
        } else {
            window.localStorage.userName = '';
            window.localStorage.passWord = '';
            window.localStorage.checkBoxValidation = '';
        }
    });
});
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {

"use strict";

    $("#submit").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

      if( $("#username").val() === "" || $("#password").val() === "" )
       { 
        $("div#error").html("Both username and password are required");
       } else {
                $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
                        $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
                        function(data) {
                          $("div#error").html(data);
                        });

                $("#myForm").submit( function() {
                   return false;
                });
               }
});

});
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'none';` Add this before the click event.

Comment: Does it throw any error in the console???

Comment: @Dev-One which click event are you referring to?

Comment: @Parag yes it does; "Uncaught TypeError: document.EventConfirmRedirection.submit is not a function"

Comment: Before submit click.

Comment: @Dev-One I tried this but it doesn't work and shows this error in the console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Comment: document.getElementById('btnSubmit').style.display = 'none';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"submit is not a function" means that you named your submit button or some other element submit. Rename the button to btnSubmit and your call will magically work. Any of the form element name and id should not be submit, otherwise form.submit will refer to that element rather than submit function.

When you name the button submit, you override the submit() function on the form.

So changing the div/submit like this will work for you

```
<div class="login"><input type="submit" value="LOGIN" name="btnSubmit" data-theme="e" id="btnSubmit"></div>
```

And if you don't want to change the button name then you might call the submit function natively aswell, which looks a bit dirty..

```
document.EventConfirmRedirection.prototype.submit.call(document.EventConfirmRedirection);
//or
document.EventConfirmRedirection.prototype.submit.call($('#myForm')[0]);
```

Comment: I've done that is still not working and still showing the same error in the console :(

Comment: @chiboz : try 2 things, 1) change id to btnSubmit aswell, 2)Also remove the type submit and then try... does it remove that error?

Comment: @chiboz : Changing name and id from submit to btnSubmit would be enough... I guess

Comment: I have another problem now, it tries to login even when the username and password input fields are blank.

Comment: small check of if(window.localStorage.userName.trim() != "") { //not empty string, submit the form} will solve your problem

Comment: Worked! Thanks again @parag.